# How to match string from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have to check title column contains color value from color column.

```
dataframe1['title'].str.contains(dataframe1['color'])
```

I am getting an error as

> > TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: try `dataframe1.apply(lambda x: x['title'].str.contains(x['color'])`

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks, it is working fine.

Comment: @Rakesh Please don't propose solutions that use apply here. There are better alternatives.

Comment: @coldspeed. Sorry I did not know. Still in the beginning stages of Pandas and numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apply` with `lambda`.

**Ex:**

```
dataframe1.apply(lambda x: x['title'].str.contains(x['color'])
```

Comment: `dataframe1.apply(lambda x: " ".join([dataframe1['brand'], dataframe1['title']]) if not x['title'].str.contains(x['brand']))` ?